# Rest controller request multiple path variables with multiple query parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest

How can we create a Rest API (Spring controller) which allows multiple path variables to have query parameters?

Where 
 1) function is a path variable and id=functionname is query parameter  
2) subfunction is a path variable and id=subfuntionname is query parameter

```
Request URL : /content/v1/clients/clientname/function?id=functionname&subfunction?id=subfunctionname
```

Update I am using matrix variations suggested by

/content/v1/clients/clientname/function;id=functionname/subfunction;id=subfunctionname 
The method shown below is not working as expected. 
What should the method definition look like?

```
 public HashMap<String, List<Model>> getContent(
        @PathVariable String clientname,            
        @MatrixVariable(name="id", pathVar="function") List<String> capabilitiesId,            
        @MatrixVariable(name="id", pathVar="subfunction") List<String> subcapabilitiesId) {
```

}

```
Error : Missing matrix variable 'id' for method parameter of type List
```

Comment: Does not look like a valid URL. There will be only one `?` and followed by `&`.

Comment: Requirement is to allow multiple functions and multiple sub functions for each function. How can this be achieved in request mapping?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please review your question and add more details to it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.
In REST controller you have two type of parameters:

- Path parameter: parameter usefull to select a resource. (a you class's method)
- Query parameter: parameter useful to send other information.

In your case I think that is a good idea send all this informations inside payload, using POST or PUT http method.

If you can't use payload you can obtain the following solution:
Request URL : /content/v1/clients/clientname/function1/function2?id1=functionnamec&id2=subfunctionaname

In this way you can create your controller with 2 path parameters and 2 query parameters:

```
@GET
@Path("/basePath/{funct1}/{funct2}")
public Response <methodName>(@PathParam("funct1") String funct1, @PathParam("funct2") String funct2, @QueryParam("id1") String id1, @QueryParam("id2") String id2)
```

Comment: You forgot "Matrix parameter", which will do almost exactly what question wants, e.g. `/content/v1/clients/clientname/funtion;id=functionnamec/subfunction;id=subfunctionaname`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With this approach function and subfunction are always constant names. How to make these path variables while defining the rest controller method?

Answer (score 0):

```
/content/v1/clients/clientname/function?id=functionnamec&subfunction?id=subfunctionaname
```

The parsing of URI is defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).  In particular, `U+003F QUESTION MARK` is a *reserved* character, the first instance of which serves a the delimiter between the relative-part and the query.

So your example breaks would parse as

```
path: /content/v1/clients/clientname/function
query: id=functionnamec&subfunction?id=subfunctionaname
```

And if we were to parse the query, as though it were an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` value....

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs("id=functionnamec&subfunction?id=subfunctionaname")
{'id': ['functionnamec'], 'subfunction?id': ['subfunctionaname']}
```

We see that the second question mark becomes part of the parameter name.

In short, it's a perfectly valid URI, but it isn't likely to produce the results that you are hoping for.

`/content/v1/clients/clientname/function/subfunction?id=functionnamec&id=subfunctionaname`

This might be usable, but there's likely to be some confusion about the duplicate id query parameters

```
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs("id=functionnamec&id=subfunctionaname")
{'id': ['functionnamec', 'subfunctionaname']}
```

`/content/v1/clients/clientname/function/subfunction?function.id=functionnamec&subfunction.id=subfunctionaname`

```
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs("function.id=functionnamec&subfunction.id=subfunctionaname")
{'function.id': ['functionnamec'], 'subfunction.id': ['subfunctionaname']}
```

That might be easier.

I think it would be common to take the data out of the query and put it on the path instead

`/content/v1/clients/clientname/function/functionname/subfunction/subfunctionaname`

And then extract the path parameters you need.